# transform: translateY() not working in Safari

Tags: html, css

I am using the CSS property transform: translateY(45%); but it isn't working in safari.

I tried a few ways

`-webkit-transform: translate(0, 45%);`

```
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-o-transform: translateY(-50%);



  transform: translateY(45%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(45%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(45%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(45%);
  -o-transform: translateY(45%);
```

My code

```css
.user-tag {
  transform: translateY(45%);
  background-color: #cbdcc0;
  color: #434b39;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="user-tag">My html</span>
    </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Both ways didn't work for me. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you please add html & css code to more elaborate your issue?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work you need to add other transform rules as well.

```css
.user-tag {
    background-color: #cbdcc0;
    color: #434b39;
    display: inline-block;
    -ms-transform: translateY(45%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(45%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(45%);
    -o-transform: translateY(45%);
    transform: translateY(45%);
}
```

```html
<td>
  <span class="user-tag">My html</span>
</td>
```

Comment: I have already mentioned above the new 4 properties  didn't work

Comment: have you tried adding with transform: translateY(45%); as well. This code is tested and works for safai may be some browser version issue could be there.

Comment: Yeah I have tested it with Safari Version 13.1.2 (14609.3.5.1.5) but it doesn't work